# Managing website with a git server

Tags: permissions, git, webserver

I have a website up and running with nginx, and I have some content in my website that I want to manage with git so that others can collaborate.

Let us say that have a user named **alice** and that the root of the website is located somewhere within alice's home directory, as in /home/alice/website/index.html

Let us also assume that I have set up a git server via gitolite for access-control, the usage of which requires setting up a dummy user that we will call **git**. There are good reasons for this user being a separate one from **alice**.

I want **alice**'s website to be able to show the content of some git repository **web_repo.git**, the origin of which is to be found in /home/git/web_repo.git, as the documentation for gitolite requires.

My first idea is to run a *post-receive* hook in the repository to sync it with some subdirectory of /home/alice/website, but that demands user **git** copying files into other user's (**alice**) home directory, which ends up in file permissions error.

There are certain constraints in my build that require the website to be hosted within **alice**'s home directory, and I can't think of a secure and elegant solution to this problem.

I have just started managing this small server and I would kindly appreciate any insights.

Comment: Why does it have to be the home directory of `alice`? Place the web root in `/var/www` where it belongs, and create a group. Put both users in that group, and set appropriate permissions on the web root directory.

Comment: cronjob for user alice to `cd  /home/alice/website/ && git pull`?  not quite as good as a post-receive hook, but updates should be reasonably fast.  (btw, remember to deny access to .git/ via the web server)

Answer (score 1):

There's thousands way of doing this !
I would proceed the following way:

First, i create a small shell script, run as user `alice` in background (tmux, screen, or event initd/systemd service).
This script would continuously :

1. Monitor a file in `/tmp/`, for example `/tmp/new_commit`.
2. When the file appears, then do the `git pull` plus eventually a `chmod -r` if needed.
3. Remove file `/tmp/new_commit`.
4. Go back to step 1.

Then i would write a git post-receive hooks on server-side to create this file on new commit and `chmod 666` it.

If you want to go more "professionnal" about that, i suggest you to look to devops and CI stuff.